# Implementing "Scheduled Executor Service"

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to write simple ScheduledExecutorService. I have a class:

```
class ScheduledExecutor {
public:
    typedef size_t TaskID;
public:
    explicit ScheduledExecutor(size_t);
    ~ScheduledExecutor();
    ScheduledExecutor(ScheduledExecutor const &) = delete;
    ScheduledExecutor(ScheduledExecutor &&) = delete;
    ScheduledExecutor & operator = (ScheduledExecutor const &) = delete;
    ScheduledExecutor & operator = (ScheduledExecutor &&) = delete;

    template<typename Fn>
    TaskID ScheduleDelayedTask(
        Fn && fn, std::chrono::milliseconds delay = 0);

    template<typename Fn>
    TaskID SchedulePeriodicTask(
        Fn && fn, std::chrono::milliseconds,
        std::chrono::milliseconds period);
    .
    .
    .
private:
    std::vector< std::thread > workers;
    std::queue< std::function<void()> > tasks;
    std::mutex queue_mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    bool stop;
};
```

I'm implemented some methods:

```
inline ScheduledExecutor::ScheduledExecutor(size_t threadPoolSize = 10) : stop(false) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; ++i) {
        workers.emplace_back(
            [this]
        {
            for (;;) {
                std::function<void()> task;
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
                    this->condition.wait(lock,
                        [this]{ return this->stop || !this->tasks.empty(); });
                    if (this->stop && this->tasks.empty())
                        return;
                    task = std::move(this->tasks.front());
                    this->tasks.pop();
                }
                task();
            }
        });
    }
}

template<typename Fn>
ScheduledExecutor::TaskID ScheduledExecutor::ScheduleDelayedTask(
    Fn && fn, std::chrono::milliseconds delay) {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
                if (stop)
                    throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");
                tasks.push(std::function<void()>(fn));
            }
    condition.notify_one();
    return 0;
}
```

The first question is: "How to add delay to first method(*TaskID ScheduleDelayedTask*)? I have an idea to wrape this function in anonymous thread (inside the method) and sleep it for delay seconds before "*condition.notify_one();*". But it is not a good way (if we have 10000 tasks with long delay? In result we will have 10000 threads which do nothing). 
**Gimme a good way to solve this problem please.**

Comment: What do you want a delayed task to do -- run after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Yep, also I have to implement the second method which can support periodic tasks (run function after "*period*" seconds). If delay = 0 -> run task immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a scheduler thread.  It wakes up when the next task to be launched is due to launch, or when some condition variable is poked.

You maintain a priority queue of "what is the next task to launch".  When something is added to the queue, if it causes the next task to be sooner, the scheduler thread is woken up by poking the condition variable.

The scheduler thread then launches the tasks waiting to run, or puts them into a ready-to-run state (if you have some kind of thread pooling).

Be careful about only running a limited subset of ready-to-run tasks, as tasks could (in theory) block on messages from other tasks (or even busy-wait), and noticing that some of your tasks have blocked is tricky.  Starving some of the tasks (by never starting them up) can cause things to grind to a halt.

One challenge is that the resolution of `std::chrono::steady_clock` on MSVC 2013 is abysmal.  And non-steady clocks can make scheduling pretty haphazard.  You want to track when the next task should start, not how long until the next task starts.

Repeating tasks are amusing, because you have to decide what happpens if one of the tasks is delayed.  Is the repeat based off the start time of the last repeat?  The end time?  What if the last task didn't get started until after the next repeat should occur?  Or even just didn't finish?  Such rules are subtle, and assuming one way or the other in client code is reasonable and convenient in different situations.

Dependency graphs are one way to approach this kind of thing, where later repeats can be explicitly dependent on the previous repeat finishing or starting.